# How to update UITableviewcell label in other method in swift3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to update a UITableviewcell's label in other method. I also saw many post on stackoverflow, non was work for me. i am using Swift 3 and I tried this one :

```
    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell : CategoryRow = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CategoryRow
```

and i am getting this error :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

i am using this in other method where i update tableviewcell label text after 24hr. 
code is here

```
var myQuoteArray = ["“If you have time to breathe you have time to meditate. You breathe when you walk. You breathe when you stand. You breathe when you lie down. – Ajahn Amaro”","We are what we repeatedly do. Excellence, therefore, is not an act but a habit. – Aristotle","The best way out is always through. – Robert Frost","“If you have time to breathe you have time to meditate. You breathe when you walk. You breathe when you stand. You breathe when you lie down. – Ajahn Amaro”","We are what we repeatedly do. Excellence, therefore, is not an act but a habit. – Aristotle","The best way out is always through. – Robert Frost"

    ]
func checkLastRetrieval(){

   //        let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
   //        let cell : CategoryRow = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CategoryRow


    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
   guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CategoryRow else { return }

    print("Getting Error line 320")// This is not printing on console

let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

if let lastRetrieval = userDefaults.dictionary(forKey: "lastRetrieval") {
if let lastDate = lastRetrieval["date"] as? NSDate {
if let index = lastRetrieval["index"] as? Int {
if abs(lastDate.timeIntervalSinceNow) > 86400 { // seconds in 24 hours
// Time to change the label
var nextIndex = index + 1

// Check to see if next incremented index is out of bounds
if self.myQuoteArray.count <= nextIndex {
// Move index back to zero? Behavior up to you...
nextIndex = 0
}



cell?.quotationLabel.text = self.myQuoteArray[nextIndex]

let lastRetrieval : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
"date" as NSObject : NSDate(),
"index" as NSObject : nextIndex as AnyObject
]

userDefaults.set(lastRetrieval, forKey: "lastRetrieval")
userDefaults.synchronize()
}
// Do nothing, not enough time has elapsed to change labels
}
}
} else {

// No dictionary found, show first quote
cell?.quotationLabel.text = self.myQuoteArray.first!

     print("line 357")
// Make new dictionary and save to NSUserDefaults
let lastRetrieval : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
"date" as NSObject : NSDate(),
"index" as NSObject : 0 as AnyObject
]

userDefaults.set(lastRetrieval, forKey: "lastRetrieval")
userDefaults.synchronize()
}

}
```

and Calling this method in ViewDidLoad()

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     checkLastRetrieval()
    }
```

what should i do? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: make CategoryRow label optional with ? instead of !

Comment: I think you are updating the cell while there are no cells in a tableview.

Comment: is this cell visible when you are trying to do that?

Comment: Nauman Malik, i've done this.But doesn't work.

Comment: Kirander,  i've a CategoryRow cell, which is working fine and other elements are properly showing in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but it doesn't work outside.

Comment: Lu,...Yes, this showing perfectly with other elements.

Comment: Please *edit* your question to show more context for this code; As it stands the answer is simple; you are force unwrapping an optional that is returning `nil` because there is no cell onscreen at [0,0] at the time you ask for it; If you show more context as to where and how these lines fit into your app we may be able to help you

Comment: @Paulw11.. Please Check updated question.

Comment: Your table view will not have been rendered in `viewDidLoad`, so there will be no cells on screen at that point.  Cells won't be onscreen until `viewDidAppear`. As I said in a comment below, the correct thing to do is update your table's data model so that the correct data is shown when the cell is subsequently loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `cellForRow(at:)` returns `nil` if the requested cell is not currently onscreen.  Since you are calling your function in `viewDidLoad` there will be no cells on screen.  This results in the crash because you have force downcast the result of `cellForRow(at:)`.

You should never use a force unwrap or a force downcast unless you are absolutely
certain the result cannot be `nil` and/or the only possible action if it is `nil` is for your app to crash.

Generally you should not update cells directly.  It is better to update the table's data model and then call `reloadRows(at:,with:)` and let your data source `cellForRow(at:)` function handle updating the cell.

If you are going to update the cell directly then make sure you use a conditional downcast with `if let` or `guard let` to avoid a crash if the cell isn't visible.  In this case you still need to update your data model so that the cell data is correct when the cell does come on screen.

Comment: Thanks Paulw11, Now i am able to getting cell properly, but my label text is not still updated.

Comment: The fact that you were trying to run the code in `viewDidLoad` makes me suspicious; if the cell is already on the screen, why would you need to run anything in `viewDidLoad`? I suspect that you are creating a new instance of the view controller and updating that, rather than updating the instance that is already on screen.  Your update seems to be time-based.  Where is the timer running?  What do you do when it fires?

Comment: As per Apple Description, i can't play timer more than 3 min, that's why i've stored my custom data in dictionary, than check it from last date than update label. May be i am doing wrong?

Comment: What I can't understand is why you are doing all of this at all; All you need to do is load the data into the table whenever the app loads and check whether the data needs to be refreshed when your app returns to the foreground.  If it does, reload the row.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `guard let` statement:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CategoryRow else { return }
```

If your `cell` type is not `CategoryRow`, you will return from the method. Try to find out why is your `cell` type not a `CategoryRow`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i've a CategoryRow cell, which is working fine and other elements are properly showing in cellForRowAtIndexPath. but it doesn't work outside.

Comment: More importantly `cellForRow(at:)` will return `nil` if the cell isn't currently on the screen; you should be prepared for this by using an `if let` or `guard let` as suggested.  Generally, you should update your data source and then reload the affected row rather than updating the cell directly.

Comment: @ChetanLodhi, where do you use this code (which method)?

Comment: V.Khambir......Actually i use this code in other method where i update label text after 24 hours. and this method is called in Viewdidload.

Comment: @ChetanLodhi, probably, at this moment you have not any cells at the IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0).

Comment: How to check if i'm getting cell label outside correctly?

Comment: switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
         let cell : CategoryRow = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CategoryRow
         
         cell.trainButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20}.... this is working fine for me.